# Are .NET GridView DataKeys secure?

Tags: security, gridview

Are .NET GridView DataKeys secure?

For instance, I put some ID into the DataKeys of some GridView, but I don't want some nefarious soul to be able to dig those ID's up from the client.

I've looked at the html source of a gridview that has some ID's stored in the DataKeys collection, and I was unable to see the ID's in open text anywhere; however, I worry that they may be stored in the ViewState - which we know isn't secure. I am hoping that the DataKeys collection is actually stored in the Session somewhere, which would make it secure - for the most part.

Anyone know the answer to this question?

Comment: what?! secure? what does this have to do with security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET rarely stores anything in the session by itself. DataKeys, just like all the other bloat, goes in the ViewState. Apart from the fact that it bloats your requests up, it should be fairly secure as long as you use the encryption features properly.

(I'm finding the need to keep mere IDs secret quite odd though, what's this about exactly?)

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say "encryption features"? With regards to your question, they're simply "secret" in that I don't want some user to go "Oh, cool, 56798 is the ID to this field, so maybe if I pass along 56799 in the URL then I can gain access to someone else's whatever." Having said that, I realize that ID's or any sort of sensitive data being passed in a URL is a risk and should therefore be encrypted, which I usually do.

Comment: @Jagd: I don't see how a numeric ID would be sensitive. You should always check if the user has the rights to touch the object before letting them do anything with it. Relying on people not being able to guess IDs is not security at all.

Comment: I'm not relying on it; I'm simply trying to make it harder for would be hackers to gain access to the ID's. It's obviously not the only security method that I have in place.

Comment: @Jagd: I'm a hacker and proud of it (I don't break into computers though, just tinker with them)